# How to make a Discord.Py random reaction game

Tags: python, discord.py

How can I  make the bot choose a right random answer (as a reaction)
And if the user gets it right send a winner message
if its wrong send a loser message.

````py
        redcrew = '<:redcrewmates:776867415514153031>'
        bluecrew = '<:bluecrewmates:776867439085617153>'
        limecrew = '<:limecrewmates:776867489866711041>'
        whitecrew = '<:whitecrewmates:776867529900425217>'
        await msg1.add_reaction(redcrew)
        await msg1.add_reaction(bluecrew)
        await msg1.add_reaction(limecrew)
        await msg1.add_reaction(whitecrew)
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == 
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('Sorry, you took too long to vote!')
        else:
            await ctx.send('hello')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(games(bot))```
    

**DONT WORRY ABOUT THE INDENTS**
````

Comment: You want the winning reaction to be a random one?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

@bot.command()
async def reaction_game(ctx):
    reactions = [
                   '<:redcrewmates:776867415514153031>', 
                   '<:bluecrewmates:776867439085617153>', 
                   '<:limecrewmates:776867489866711041>',
                   '<:whitecrewmates:776867529900425217>'
                 ]
    winning_reaction = random.choice(reactions)
    
    message = await ctx.send('some message')
    for reaction in reactions:
        await ctx.add_reaction(reaction)


    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction) == winning_reaction

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=60.0)
        await ctx.send('You reacted with the winning emoji')
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send('You took too long to react')
    else:
        await ctx.send('hello')
```